# iOS - how to save hyperlinks in sqlite?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, hyperlink, save

How to save hyperlinks in sqlite.

I tried saving it as a string but something like this has been saved in my column -

```
HYPERLINK "HYPERLINKHYPERLINKwwwHYPERLINK.HYPERLINKyoutubeHYPERLINK.HYPERLINKcomHYPERLINK/HYPERLINKwatchHYPERLINK?HYPERLINKvHYPERLINK=HYPERLINKurHYPERLINK_HYPERLINKairHYPERLINK_HYPERLINKPcWo
```

is there any special way to treat hyperlinks in iOS development.

I am a newbie in iOS world so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: From where are you getting the "hyperlink"? There's no UIHyperlinkView or anything like that in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a bit random, but you can always remove the hyperlinks to get the URL from that string:

```
columnStringVar = [columnStringVar stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"HYPERLINK" withString:@""];
```